# UIImageView animation from left to right

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, core-animation

I want to move my `UIImageView` from left to right and vice versa. I accomplish half of it by using the following code:

```
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

CGPoint pos = mover.center;
pos.x = 100.0f;
mover.center = pos;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Where `mover` is a `UIImageView`. The problem I am facing is that I am unable to move it from left to right completely. The above code is only moving it from right to center. I want to go further left from center. Can anybody guide me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think `UIKit` animations provide you direct key frame animations to get the oscillation effect. We can try to achieve it using delegates by triggering one animation after another but it is not as efficient as `CAKeyframeAnimation`. To use this, you will have to include the `QuartzCore` framework in your project and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`. You can achieve your oscillation effect by doing something like this,

```
self.mover.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation;

animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
animation.duration = 3.0f;
animation.repeatCount = 10;
animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:160.0f],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:320.0f],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:160.0f],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:160.0f], nil]; 
animation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.25],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.5], 
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.75],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];    

animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[self.mover.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

This snippet of code oscillates a view left to right pretty close to your description although to get the exact effect you want you might have to change it a little.

Comment: that was just an example, i didn't put 100 for x pos actually, and well this answer is not helpful because i wanted to move it left and right. You just explained one side movement which I have already done :(

Comment: @Wasim Your question didn't mention that there was no animation at all. So I misunderstood your requirement. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks for reply :) but you still misunderstood my question :) I said that i half accomplished the animation which means that I am able to animate my UIViewImage from center to right or left. But my  main motive is to start animation from center of the screen and move it first to extreme left and then extreme right. I hope my question is more clear to you now :) Sorry for disturbing you again n again :)

Comment: First of all so sorry for replying very late because i was busy in a .Net project :) and thanks a ton Deepak your code works great and it helped me alot of what i wanted to do :) I will manage it however and will be make for my use. Thanks a lot again.. !

Comment: @Deepak is there any way that using the above code i can do more animation after completing the above animation ?

Comment: You can do `animation.delegate = self;` and implement [`animationDidStop:finished:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004494-CH1-DontLinkElementID_9) method.

Comment: ok i will check it out too. I know about animationDidStop but didnt know how to use it in your given code. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you can target iOS4, this can be achieved by

```
   typedef void (^completionBlock)(BOOL);
   completionBlock moveToExtremeRight = ^(BOOL finished){
       // animate, with repetition, from extreme left to extreme right 
       [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 // twice as long!
                          delay:0.0
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationAutoReverse
                     animations:^{
                          mover.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 0);
                     }
                     completion:nil
       ];
   };
   mover.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
   // animate once, to the extreme left
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                          // or whatever is appropriate 'extreme left'
                          mover.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, 0);
                     }
                     // on completion, start a repeating animation
                     completion:moveToExtremeRight
   ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting center you should look into setting the transform. With center you set the center which means you have to calculate the center correctly in relation to the image size.

To move it left set the transform to a translation of -320. To move it back set it to the identitiy transform.